# VBS - Drop down list generates default option every other line

Tags: vbscript

My VBS drop down list is displaying the option "All" every other listing.

I know that the problem is somewhere in my option values, but I'm not sure how to fix this, help would be appreciated.

```
<% 
Dim DataConn
Dim customersel
Dim SQL

Set DataConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set customersel = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
%>

<%
DataConn.Open "DSN=***;UID=***;PWD=***"

SQL = "select customername FROM log.dbo.customer order by customerName"
customersel.Open SQL, DataConn
%>

<select Name="customersel" id="customersel">
<%While Not customersel.EOF%>
<% if Request.Form("customersel") = "0" then %>
<option value="0" selected>All
<% else %>
<option value="0">All
<% end if %>
<option value="<%= customersel("customername") %>"><%= customersel("customername") %></option>

<%
customersel.MoveNext
Wend

customersel.Close
Set customersel = Nothing
DataConn.Close
Set DataConn = Nothing
%>
</select>
```

Trudeau Fernandes solution:

```
    <select Name="customersel" id="customersel">
    <% if Request.Form("customersel") = "0" then %>
    <option value="0" selected>All</option>
    <% else %>
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <% end if %>
    <%While Not customersel.EOF%>
    <option value="<%= customersel("customername") %>"><%= customersel("customername") %></option>
```

Comment: Move the if condition outside (before) the loop.. You have also not put </option> for the All option

Comment: Ugh. Thank you very much. I thought that it was something silly like that. How do I mark your response as the answer?

Comment: Not sure.. May be u cud vote up the comment or I will add an answer.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the if block outside the loop.. And  make sure u close the option tag for the 'All' option..

Comment: Thanks again. I added your suggestion to the original as well.